# Which one is the fastest beween Set and Maps in Java?

Tags: java, performance

Which structure should I use if I need to have several operations of add and remove items into my collection? I need to have the quickest result, and obviously the most efficent one

Comment: You should use the one that holds the data you care about.  Maps and sets don't store the same thing.  Also, `Map` and `Set` are interfaces, and the performance is going to be determined by the implementation.  For instance, a `HashMap` and a `TreeMap` are going perform differently for different operations.

Comment: Maps and Sets have different properties... I feel your question is not really relevant

Comment: Suggestion: implement a test. Do 20,000 operations on one and 20,000 operations on the other, with timing in between. If that's not enough to get useful results, switch it to 1,00,000 operations, or whatever it takes.

Comment: @D.Lawrence See the answer by Koiix. Under the hood, a set is normally backed by a map.

Comment: @Paul true true. However, it makes more sense to use an adequate data structure for a given use case than using a data structure just for the sake of performance. That was my point.

Comment: @D.Lawrence Sorry, my comment was not clear. I agree about using the right tool for the job, though in this case the job is "performance" and not "being a set" :)  The funny and interesting thing (to me) is that `Set` and `Map` are the same internally which is why the question isn't relevant.  It's a still good question IMO because that is not common knowledge unless one has looked at the source code for `java.util.HashSet`, e.g.

Comment: @VGR I know that it's not a huge difference but my teacher wants us to use the best item for each program he gives us to do... So i have asked that because he asks frequently us to choose between one of the elements of the collection... In his opinion use a Set or a Map (obviously HashSet, HashMap and so on...) is something really important to choose properly... He wants us to make small programs but thinking in big, that's why I asked so

Answer (score 2):

A Set is typically implemented by using a Map. It is basically a map with the added functionality of not allowing duplicate values. This added functionality makes it slower than typical implementations of maps. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the **All Known Implementing Classes** list of [java.util.Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface. Each implementation can be used for different scenarios.

You may find multiple collections which fulfill your needs. At this point, I would weigh the benefits each bring to my needs and compare with the performance for operations such as adding, removing, iterating, etc.